# PHP no-framework-tutorial class not found

Tags: php, autoload, fastroute

I try to build test project with [PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial](https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial)
My Controllers/BaseController.php:

```
<?php

namespace Example\Controllers;

class BaseController
{
    public function test(){
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

And index.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Example;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

// come code with routes

case \FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
        $className = $routeInfo[1][0];
        $method = $routeInfo[1][1];
        $vars = $routeInfo[2];

        $class = new $className; <-- load the class specified in the routes
        $class->$method($vars);
        break;

// some code
```

When I tried run this code I got error:

> Class 'Example\Controllers\BaseController' not found

Can you please tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: `Examples` is not `Example`.

Comment: Copy paste error) 
I got error: Class 'Example\Controllers\BaseController' not found

Comment: Forgot to regenerate the autoloader?

Comment: composer dump-autoload?
Does not help(((